# Kotlin dialog looks cramped / weird

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, dialog

[image]

I designed a layout for custom dialog and i am showing it. But it looks weird as you can see at the picture. In the layout file, nothing seems wrong and in the layout preview everything looks fine too. Whats wrong?

My Layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/calendarYellow"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventTitleText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="Play football with friends"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventTimeText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_time"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="  SS - SS"
                    android:textColor="@color/blumedWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventTitleText" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventTypeK"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_event_white"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayout2">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cons"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:text="Hatırlatıcılar"
                        android:textColor="@color/noteTitleColor"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_goneMarginTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="40dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/remindersTextTouchable"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_drop_down"
                        android:text="5 dakika önce"
                        android:textColor="@color/categoriesLogoColor"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/guestsText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:text="Misafirler"
                    android:textColor="@color/noteTitleColor"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cons"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/guestsReal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="null"
                    android:textColor="@color/categoriesLogoColor"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guestsText"
                    android:paddingBottom="30dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guestsReal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how i call the dialog;

```
val dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.event_show_dialog)
dialog.setCancelable(true)
dialog.show()
```

I thinked it may happen because of this constarint things. I tried something but i cant fix it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout's width is `match_parent` which means the `Dialog` decides how wide it should be, and apparently that's not very wide at all! You should probably change your layout so it uses `wrap_content` instead (or a fixed width if you want), [that's how the example with a custom view does it](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#CustomLayout)

It's also recommended you use `AlertDialog` instead of using `Dialog` directly, if you read the start of that page. It goes over some of the things you need to consider (e.g. maybe using a `DialogFragment`) in case you're not already aware and doing that.